# IBM Watson IoT platform : historical data is empty

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

I try to do the POC on IBM Watson IoT platform. I have followed the document in this link for creating the device simulator.
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/nodereddevice_sample.html#devices

It can connect and send the MQTT message event to IoT platform but when I try to get the historical data from REST API, it always returns empty.
https://os9c6l.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0002/historian

Not sure what when wrong.

Comment: Have you turned the historian on (it is off by default)?

Comment: When I just tried this for my own test environment using Firefox Poster and an api key/token generated in IoTP dashboard access section for user/pass, I got 401 unauthorized, which at least indicates something might be the. Do you get the same 401?

Comment: I did not get the 401 from my test. Anyway after having a discussion with IBM guy. They told me that they are going to have a option to use CloudantDB for keeping the historical data. So it should be fine for me then. Thank you very much Barny.

Comment: I got it working (part of solution was switching away from Poster) have some historical data today - see idan's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the IoT Watson IoT Platform dashboard connected to your BlueMix app, go to settings and there is a setting for Time Series DB which defaults to Off. When you turn it on you also get to choose the storage duration.

Comment: I have already turned it on and set it for 1 month but it does not help.

Comment: Can you try to delete and add your device again?  While time series is already on.

Answer (score 0):

if the Time Series DB was off and the device was added, you might not be able to see it even if you set the historian on on. Try and re-add the device.

Comment: I spoke to IBM support, then I tried a different app from Poster, I used RESTClient, and got a 200 response, and an empty JSON object for data. Then I was told that Historian only records data for devices added after it is turned on, so to delete the device and re-add it. Also there was apparently a problem yesterday with historian. Anyway, now it works, I have some historical data which was provided by the temp sensor on my Pi. Key thing is as idan says if your device already existed before turning Historian on, delete the device and re-add it.